# How to decorate data in a matrix for reporting purposes?

Tags: programming, list-manipulation, output-formatting

I want to create a report from two matrices m1 and m2 (already created, and available) with data.

The report should (roughly) look like the output of the following code:

```
ClearAll[sa];
sa = SparseArray[Table["", 5, 5]];
sa[[1, 1]] = "0\n1" ;
sa[[2, 1]] = "1\n25";
sa[[3, 1]] = "2\n4";
sa[[3, 2]] = "11\n30";
sa[[4, 1]] = "3\n2";
sa[[4, 2]] = "21\n15";
sa[[4, 3]] = "111\n5";
sa[[5, 1]] = "4\n2";
sa[[5, 2]] = "31\n5";
sa[[5, 3]] = "22\n2";
sa[[5, 4]] = "211\n3";
sa[[5, 5]] = "1111\n0";
sa // MatrixForm
```

The data before the newline ( \n ) comes from the first matrix m1, the data after the newline comes from the second matrix m1.

In fact m1 contains textual headings for the data in m2.

My question is in fact, given a matrix containing only data like, for example:

```
ClearAll[sa];
sa = SparseArray[Table["", 5, 5]];
sa[[1, 1]] = 1 ;
sa[[2, 1]] = 25;
sa[[3, 1]] = 4;
sa[[3, 2]] = 30;
sa[[4, 1]] = 2;
sa[[4, 2]] = 15;
sa[[4, 3]] = 5;
sa[[5, 1]] = 2;
sa[[5, 2]] = 5;
sa[[5, 3]] = 2;
sa[[5, 4]] = 3;
sa[[5, 5]] = 0;
sa // MatrixForm
```

Then, what is the best strategy to decorate the cell elements with all sorts of textual attributes, color, etc., and in my case a textual heading?

Note that the data and the data for the cell heading texts are initially stored in two matrices and that I am best helped with a general strategy to decorate data in a matrix for reporting purposes.

Finally, what is the best function to produce the report?

Comment: Take a look at [Grid](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GridsRowsAndColumns.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I have looked at Grid, but alas doesn't answer all my questions.

Comment: Have you looked at all of the `Options` of `Grid`? What functionality do you need that is missing?

Comment: Yes, I use it often. If only there was something like ItemHeading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed `sa = SparseArray[Table["", 5, 5]];` to `sa = ConstantArray["", {5, 5}, SparseArray];` in the second code block.

```
decorate = ToString[Style[#, Italic, Bold, RandomColor[], 
   RandomInteger[{14,24}]], StandardForm]&;

itemheadings = {0, 1, 2, 11, 3, 21, 111, 4, 31, 22, 211, 1111};

styledheadings = decorate /@ itemheadings;
nzp = sa["NonzeroPositions"];
nzv = sa["NonzeroValues"];
newvalues = StringRiffle[#, "\n"] & /@ Transpose[{styledheadings, ToString /@ nzv}];

report = SparseArray[nzp -> newvalues, {5, 5}, ""];
report  // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Alternatively, let

```
m2 = SparseArray[nzp -> styledheadings, Automatic,""];
```

define `newvalues` as

```
newvalues = StringRiffle[#, "\n"] & /@ Transpose[{m2["NonzeroValues"], ToString /@ nzv}];
```

We can also `Riffle` two matrices and use `Grid`:

```
m1 = sa;
m2 = SparseArray[nzp -> itemheadings, Automatic, ""];
styledm2 = Map[decorate, m2, {-1}];
Grid[Riffle[styledm2, m1], Dividers -> {False, {{True, False}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps a lot.

Comment: @nilo, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.